# Bag of Holding ‘bomb’ and Immovable rods

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Scenario - My PC was faced with an unwinnable battle and decided to cast invisibility, sneak up the lead bad guy, toss a bag of holding into another bag of holding, essentially clearing out a 10x10 space of bad guys, including the leader.

Now here is the contestable part - The PC that essentially executed the ‘bag bomb’ placed two immovable rods tied to a rope of climbing to keep in the current plane and not be sucked into the Astral plane.

As the DM, I am struggling with - Does the Bag of Holding inside a bag of holding cause a force blast into the Astral plane or is it a teleportation - ‘blink and you are gone’ kinda of experience?  Depending on the answer, then did he and the rods all get sucked or teleported through? Do I require a strength check to see if he held on and if so, vs what DC? Would the force of the ‘sucking’ be so great that he suffers damage?  What would be the damage?  Would he lose all of his belongings on person?

Help please!

Comment: Adeptus and @Darth Pseudonym - thanks for the quick and insightful responses.  We continued our session (and finished Hoard of the Dragon Queen) and I decided that the PC (Immovable Rods and all on his person) was instantly teleported to the Astral Plane. He is an experienced player and took it like a champ. The party’s success was recognized by Bahamut who has sent emissaries to the Astral plane to seek out the Githyanki or the Githzerai for assistance in locating the PC (who probably saved the party) whether he be dead or alive.

Answer (score 19):

All the rules tell us about destroying a [Bag of Holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) like that, is:

> Placing a bag of holding inside an extradimensional space created by a handy haversack, portable hole, or similar item instantly destroys both items and opens a gate to the Astral Plane. The gate originates where the one item was placed inside the other. **Any creature within 10 feet of the gate is sucked through it to a random location on the Astral Plane.** The gate then closes. The gate is one-way only and can't be reopened.

(Note, you say *clearing a 10x10 space*... it will actually be a circle with 10 feet radius or **20 feet diameter**)

The [Immovable Rod](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/immovable-rod) is not *entirely* immovable:

> The rod can hold up to **8,000 pounds of weight**. More weight causes the rod to deactivate and fall. A creature can use an action to make a **DC 30 Strength check**, moving the fixed rod up to 10 feet on a success.

Some creatures are strong enough to move it. No creature is strong enough to avoid being sucked into the Astral plane by the Bag of Holding imploding.

The "sucking" isn't described with any chance to resist, or with any risk of damage. So I'd assume that there is neither. Anyone in range *will* be sucked through, but will *not* be harmed in the process.

Answer (score 9):

The gate here does not list any save DC to resist the effect, and the effect happens instantaneously, so it seems to me that "sucked through" in this context doesn't mean 'dragged across the ground towards a doorway', but rather that the whole 10-foot-sphere is instantly translocated to the Astral Plane, but without bisecting any large creatures that are only halfway into the area.

Allowing this sort of stunt could be a dangerous precedent to set. The Artificer can infuse a pair of brand new Bags of Holding just by taking a long rest, so destroying two to pull this off has no real cost and could easily become a go-to strategy rather than a last-ditch desperation move.

A player who tried to pull this in my game would find himself on the Astral Plane with a very angry bad guy and a ten-foot segment of rope that terminates in a severed, smoking end.

Comment: Since the teleportation is random I would vote to them both ending up in the Astral plane with a reasonably different locations. Would make for a fun scene and possibly for an interesting story: trying to locate the missing friend in the Astral before the Big Bad gets to him.

Comment: You could certainly run it that way.  I've always read it as saying that the gate's target location is random, but everything that goes through the gate ends up in about the same area.